# Getting a state hook value from imported function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get a value from the state hook that is stored in special function. There is no problem to do this when the component is a function. For example, I do like this in `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavigationBar } from '../';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { GlobalStyles } from '../global';
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from '../theme';
import { useDarkMode } from '../useDarkMode';

const App = (props) => {

  const [ theme, toggleTheme ] = useDarkMode();
  const themeMode = theme === 'light' ? lightTheme : darkTheme;

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
      <div>
        <GlobalStyles />  
        <NavigationBar theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

But I need to get the `theme` state value in the same way, but in another component that is declared like a class. I am trying to do this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDarkMode } from '../useDarkMode';

class CodeBlock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const { prop } = this.props;
    const [ theme, toggleTheme  ] = useDarkMode();
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

export default CodeBlock;
```

This code returns an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

So, how can I get this state's value correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to have different themes in different parts of the app? Or a single theme, that's then made available to any component that wants it via ThemeProvider? it's not possible to use `useDarkMode` in a class component, but i suspect that's not actually what you want, as that would be trying to create a new theme, unrelated to the one in `App`.

Comment: Its exactly what the error says: "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a **function** component." You're using it within a **class** component.

Comment: convert your class component into a function component, it's not too much work and you can provide the exact same functionalities with function components

Comment: What @NicholasTower said. You probably want to use the **Context** to store the theme preference. See here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html and to use them in class components, see https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React hooks can't be used inside class based components. They need to be used in functional components. Your `App.js` is an example of a functional component because it does not use a class definition `class MyComponent extends React.Component`. To fix your error you just need to change your class based component into a functional component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDarkMode } from '../useDarkMode';

const CodeBlock = (props) => {
  const { prop } = props;
  const [ theme, toggleTheme  ] = useDarkMode();
  return (
    ...
  );
}

export default CodeBlock;
```

[Read more about functional and class components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

[Read more about hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)